# Setting the URL field of an EKEvent

Tags: iphone, calendar

Title sums it up. `URL` isn't an `EKEvent` property but figured maybe there's some hidden way of setting it, especially considering it's printed when you log an `EKEvent` object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you're on iOS 5 Beta? `EKEvents` shouldn't have a URL property pre-5.0

Take a look at `EKCalendarItem` on the 5.0 SDK. `EKEvent` is being phased out, and it's superclass changed from `NSObject` to `EKCalendarItem`.

EKCalendarItem has the `@property(nonatomic, copy) NSURL *URL`

Comment: That great to know! Thanks for breaking the NDA for the sake of my question :P